# Aurelia pass configuration to plugin or feature

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to pass some configuration information into my aurelia feature but I am not sure how. I found no documentation on how do this in the aurelia docs.

My Feature

**Main.js**

```
.feature('aurelia-scrollbar', config => {
    // I want to pass an object along this
    config.foo = { bar: 'yay' }
 })
```

**Index.js**

```
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources('./scrollbar');
}
```

**Scrollbar.js**

```
import Scrollbar from 'smooth-scrollbar';
import 'smooth-scrollbar/dist/smooth-scrollbar.css!';

export class ScrollbarCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    Scrollbar.init(this.element); // I want to use the passed configuration option here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `feature` method (and `plugin` method) will accept your feature-specific configuration as a parameter:

*main.js*

```js
let scrollbarConfig = { foo: 'bar' };

aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .feature('aurelia-scrollbar', scrollbarConfig);
```

In your feature's configure method, register the config object in the container.

*aurelia-scrollbar/index.js*

```js
export function configure(frameworkConfiguration, scrollbarConfig) {
  frameworkConfiguration.globalResources('./scrollbar');
  frameworkConfiguration.container.registerInstance('scrollbar-config', scrollbarConfig);
}
```

Anything that depends on the configuration can use the container to retrieve it:

*aurelia-scrollbar/scrollbar.js*

```js
@inject(Element, 'scrollbar-config')
export class Scrollbar {
  constructor(element, scrollbarConfig) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

GitHub issue to add this information to the Aurelia documentation: https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/570